# What is "athlete of distinction"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

"...An all-round amateur **athlete of distinction** and until recently tutor of English literature at..."

Could anybody provide an explanation, please?

Comment: Did you look up “distinction” in a dictionary? If you’re not able to understand the meaning from that, please edit your question to include what you don’t understand there.

Comment: I did not. Now I have read the article on "distinction" on thefreedictionary and found the example: *a man of distinction*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be distinct or to distinguish one's self is to be exceptional, to stand out from a crowd. So describing someone as an *athlete of distinction* is to say the athlete has won some exceptional awards or accolades.

Comment: I find this conflicting - amateur and distinct. I can't consider an amateur athlete as exceptional.

Comment: @EvgeniNabokov Amateur means unpaid, not how good someone is. Though it’s fair to assume he is distinguished *compared to other amateurs* unless the context directly mentions a comparison to professionals.

Comment: @StephenS Yeah, probably among *tutors of English literature* that athlete is distinctive.